Python 3 type hints do not differentiate between `bytes` and `str`
Consider the following functions:
def abc(o:bytes):
    print(o)

def xyz(o:str):
    print(o)

Invariant of whether I pass a str or bytes object, I see the functions working. I would have expected an error for type mismatch, but no such thing happens:
>>> abc('abc')
abc
>>> abc(b'abc')
b'abc'
>>> xyz('xyz')
xyz
>>> xyz(b'xyz')
b'xyz'

What does the PEP standard say about this? Other than explicitly checking for type, is there a way to prevent this?

Type hints are used by static analysis tools.  Python itself doesn't care.

If you run mypy or pyright or another static analysis tool on your code, you will see issues. But as Mark said above, Python itself doesn't care.

If you don't want such behaviour use a different language

From PEP 484 - Type Hints:

It should also be emphasized that Python will remain a dynamically typed language, and the authors have no desire to ever make type hints mandatory, even by convention.

